# Merge tag deprecated into deprecation-warning

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Content tags [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deprecated) and [deprecation-warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deprecation-warning) are essentially the same thing.
So these could be merged; I'd prefer [deprecation-warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deprecation-warning), but this is more work.

Comment: I don't see that so the warning can be ignored, if something's Ng is deprecated you don't get a message

Comment: When tagging one gets both options suggested, while one option would be better...while I don't understand "if something's Ng is deprecated". English please.

Comment: Auto correction modifies the text .i overlooked the changes. I meant when something is deprecated you don't get a message , only an error that there is something wrong

Comment: Why would we merge them? If they're "essentially the same thing", that's what synonyms are for.

Comment: Both these seem like meta tags to me anyway. A burn might be in order

Comment: @nbk *"I meant when something is deprecated you don't get a message , only an error that there is something wrong"* - Not necessarily, while deprecated things _may_ be immediately removed and may be listed as removed due to deprecation (and it will depend on the developer/team and how they convey removals), deprecation is _normally_ a status applied to something _prior_ to (a potential, future) removal, and is warned about rather than an error.

Comment: These kind of warnings are basically a suggestion to upgrade before a future update might break it. It's kind of a meta tag, but a common one to search for, because it's always about API changes, which may cause massive log spam - while one may prefer a shorter build log. It's always combined with other tags, alone the tag wouldn't make sense; more of a sub-category to any language tag.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say I am an expert in deprecation warnings. What do I know?

These tags are not suitable for Stack Overflow as they don't actually describe the content of the question. Both should be burninated and removed from the site.

Comment: When copy & paste searching by log message eg. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72396263/549372), it reflects the content of the question - where the expected answer is always the new class or method, which substitutes the deprecated one. I'd agree as far as this tag by itself has no meaning - but combined with eg. PHP or Java, it has. When only knowing JavaScript, one might not understand it's meaning.

Comment: Radically burning everything that isn't a product name may reduce the site's searchability - because when searching by class or method, one is not interested in how to use that (it's all irrelevant answers), but what else to use (the current answer). That's why this combination tag helps finding.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case. If I want to find out how to fix a deprecation warning on a specific topic, this tag might help me find it.